# What's installed and running on a Centos server?

Tags: centos

I have a couple of Centos servers that were setup by someone no longer with the company.  What's the best way to find what's installed and running?

Answer (score 5):

You can get a list of current running processes using `ps`:

```
# ps -fe
```

You can see what services are configured to start at boot using `chkconfig`:

```
# chkconfig --list
```

Additionally, you can look in `/etc/rc.d/rc3.d` (or `rc5.d`, depending on your default runlevel) to get similar information (but this will also show startup scripts that don't make use of `chkconfig`).

You can get a list of software installed using `yum` and `rpm` using `rpm`:

```
# rpm -qa
```

Or yum:

```
# yum list installed
```

Answer (score 2):

Also check /etc/rc.local for any entries which weren't listed in the /etc/rc.d directory.

I would also check the /opt directory. Some programs tend to put their files there.

Comment: Excellent additional examples of places where hand-edits tend to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the obvious `chckconfig --list` and `rpm -qa`, don't forget to do some manual checks in case the previous admin installed things manually.  Some things to check:

- What files are installed under `/usr/local`?

  - In particular, is there anything in `/usr/local/etc`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/usr/local/sbin`?
- Are there any hand-edits of /etc/crontab, indicating special cron jobs?
- Are there any manually added entries in `/etc/cron.*/` dirs?
- Are there any special scripts in `/root/bin`?
- Is there a crontab for root (run `crontab -l` as root)?
- Are there any weird uses listed in `/etc/passwd`?

  - that is, any users that seem to be hand-added for running special tasks?

those are a few places to check to get a sense of what manual changes have been performed on the machine, separate from regular packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can list the services that are running/not running by typing:

service --status-all